# Vue 3 make same multiple cards with different contents

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I got this result: Content got double but, not cloning as a card element

[image: Content got double but, not cloning as a card element]

here's the code

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

defineProps({
  project: String,
});

const projectList = ref([
  {
    img: './src/assets/img/Pp.png',
    tag: 'React JS',
    name: 'Destination List App',
    desc: 'Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas..',
  },
  {
    img: './src/assets/img/PP2.png',
    tag: 'HTML CSS JS',
    name: 'City Specialties App',
    desc: 'Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas..',
  },
]);
</script>
```

and here is the template tag

```html
<div>
  <!-- I want this whole element below to be multiplied -->
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card card--project">
      <img class="card__img" v-for="project in projectList" v-bind:key="project.img" :src="project.img" alt="" />
      <div class="card__text">
        <p class="project-label text-md text-md--md" v-for="project in projectList" v-bind:key="project.tag">{{ project.tag }}</p>
        <h4 class="text-gradient-primary" v-for="project in projectList" v-bind:key="project.name">{{ project.name }}</h4>
        <p class="project-desc text-md" v-for="project in projectList" v-bind:key="project.desc">{{ project.desc }}</p>
        <a href="#" class="links">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make a card section that look like this

[image: desired result]

Comment: What is the issue you are encountering ? What have you tried to solve it ?

Comment: This is a CSS thing, not a Vue3 issue. I also removed the Vue2 tag.

Comment: sorry, and thank you for the response. The content got double in 1 card element, the result i want is that'll make a multiple card with different content, i've tried to place this line `v-for="project in projectList" v-bind:key="project.name"` in the same line as div.col-md-3, but also not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are looping all the images, tags, etc individually. As you said you want the whole element to be multiplied in your comments, that's what you need to do, loop the whole card.

```
<div>
   <!-- I want this whole element below to be multiplied -->
   <div class="col-md-4" v-for="(project,id) in projectList" v- 
       bind:key="project.id" >
        <div class="card card--project">
       <img class="card__img" " :src="project.img" alt="" />
       <div class="card__text">
        <p class="project-label text-md text-md--md" >{{ project.tag }}</p>
        <h4 class="text-gradient-primary">{{ project.name }}</h4>
        <p class="project-desc text-md" >{{ project.desc }}</p>
        <a href="#" class="links">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution works awesome for me, there's some error in my code when i write this solution. `v-for="(project,id) in projectList" v-bind:key="project.id"` says that id never called, so i delete the **id** it become like this `v-for="project in projectList" v-bind:key="project.id">`, thank you for the answer.